# Magento 2.3.2 product save very slow with Varnish cache enabled

Tags: varnish, magento2.3.2

I have a very fast Magento 2 backend, I have configured Varnish caching. When I save any product, it takes about 20 seconds to save while loading the product edit page goes very fast. Saving category pages are also slow while saving customer data it's very fast. So it must be something with the cache invalidation I think.

The moment I switch back to inbuild cache, it's very fast again. No changes in IP's etc. I checked the cache purge IP's but it looks like there is no issue.

I have upgraded from Magento 2.1.9 to 2.3.2. Probably there's an issue. I have a fresh Magento 2 installation, on the same server that doesn't have that problem.

Also, my Varnish server is a seperate server. I host them both in Azure. They are both in different subscriptions, networks are peered. At first I thought that the problem could be a network issue but than the second Magento 2 installation should have the same problems. Both server can reach each other on port 80 and 443.

I checked varnishncsa and varnishlog, I can't find any errors.

Any idea's?

Comment: Is it a multisite? I noticed significant slow down in admin product save once more stores had been added. Checking sql and profiling it is the overhead of indexing store specific values. Only option was to configure index on schedule.

Comment: I just remembered I created some shell scripts which I used to debug and profile a slow store. Basically perform various data actions. Check each one to confirm it's doing something you approve if you choose to run https://github.com/DominicWatts/Benchmark

Comment: It's not even a multisite, just one site. Thank you for your Benchmark tool, works good on 2.3.2. I didn't test it on my live site though.

Comment: I added an additional Varnish server in the same network, but same problems so it's not a working issue.

Comment: Can you turn on mysql slow query log on? I'm wondering if what's happening is that you having varnish configured is adding overhead as additional queries are being used to build a cache invalidate request which is sent to varnish server.  Another thing to check is a product within a single category (or perhaps no category) vs a product which is in a lot of deep categories.  See if the timings match (or are similar)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not a mysql issue either, it shows nothing. I tested it with SELECT SLEEP(15); and that did show the query in the logs so it's not a mysql problem.

Comment: One other idea is that the varnish cache is slow to respond to cache invalidate request either because too much is being invalidated or varnish is misconfigured.  Have you tried a health check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-advanced.html#health or perhaps https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/users-guide/vcl-backends.html?highlight=health%20check#health-checks that's pretty much most of my knowledge on the subject. Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the problem either. The problem is somewhere in Magento because on the same server, a new Magento setup works just fine. I guess I need to migrate my website :(
Thanks anyway for your help Dominic!

Comment: Did you get anywhere on this. I think I've got the same scenario

Comment: No unfortunately not. I tried everything. I just don't use Varnish caching anymore for this particular website.

Answer (score 0):

For others which are running into this problem. Then PURGE isn't working. You need to add / edit http_cache_hosts in env.php.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's both http_cache_hosts and AWS security group settings. In order for varnish to need in two different servers, in the security group of varnish you should enable 6081 inbound port to Magento servers.

http_cache_hosts you can set up like ([How cache clearing works with Varnish](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/varnish/use-varnish-cache.html))

```
bin/magento setup:config:set --http-cache-hosts=192.0.2.100,192.0.2.155:6081
```

Also, do not forget to add your magento server CIDR block in acl purge section of varnish.

```
acl purge {
"172.31.0.0/255.255.0.0";
"localhost";
```

}